# How to set aspect ratio in stack view?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am trying to improve my app to looks the same on every iPhone device. I started designing on iPhone 8 plus.
I added 3 buttons to the view and set 3 constraints(width/height and aspect ratio) `1st button = Width:300 Height: 65 aspect ratio 
2nd button = Width: 175 Height: 65 aspect ratio 
3rd button = Width: 200 Height: 65 aspect ratio`

I added them to stackView and set some options`(axis: vertical , alignment: center ,distribution: fill proportionally, spacing: 19)` 
Now i want to set the stackView so it will looks exactly the same on every device.[image: my storyboard]. When i add 3 constraints (top/right/left + aspect ratio) i dont get the results i want. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: did you set the constraints of stack view?

Comment: Yes , for example i set top:0 , left:50 ,right:50 and aspect ratio , and it looks different on every iphone device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set stackView distribution = `FillEqually` , then when you give stackView these constraints

> top , left , right and aspect ratio

any item will have it's height resized , and give each one the aspect you want so the width will stretch accordingly

Comment: i set  stackView distribution and constraints to (top:50,left:50,right:50 aspect ratio) and still have the same problem, it doesnt look the same on every device. ( for example on iphone SE the 1st button is outside the view)

Comment: what aspect you set to the stack ??

Comment: according to your aspects , the first button width will be 262 despite the stack width is 220 => 320 (iphoneSE width ) - (50+50) = 220 which will exceed stack width , so you need to decrease the aspect ratio of this button or of the stack

Comment: BTW you will encounter this in any design that want to accomodate aspect ratio and different screen sizes , you may also set the constraints programmatically according to device size , as size classes of auto-layout may not help on this issue

Comment: **i didint change them** you have to change to your needs autolayout create an aspect according to the current size of the stack it's not obligatory

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, i understand the problem now.